# Split string on 2nd occurrence of characters JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I want to split a string using a comma and need to populate an array of JSON. I have the following string data

```
const test='00000001,name1,00000002,name2,00000003,name3,00000004,name4';

console.log(test.split('/[\n,|]/',2));

Output : ['00000001','name1','00000002','name2','00000003','name3','00000004','name4']
```

But I need output like this

```
[{id:'00000001',name:'name1'},{id:'00000002',name:'name2'},{id:'00000003',name:'name3'},{id:'00000004',name:'name4'}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result by first match the strings with `/(\d)+,(\w)+/gi`. It will give you an array of strings.

Then you can use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the desired result.

```js
const test = "00000001,name1,00000002,name2,00000003,name3,00000004,name4";

const regex = /(\d)+,(\w)+/gi;
const result = test.match(regex).map((str) => {
  const [id, name] = str.split(",");
  return { id, name };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Map function to cast your couple key value

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map?retiredLocale=it

Comment: There are other methods much more suitable for the task than `map`, which is "semantically" not purposed to do what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array is of even length, this output can be achieved by doing :

```js
const test='00000001,name1,00000002,name2,00000003,name3,00000004,name4';
let words = test.split(",");
let output = [];
let obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
  obj = {};
  obj["id"] = words[i];
  }
  
  else {
  obj["name"] = words[i];
  output.push(obj);
  }
}
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be using a pattern with [named capture groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges).

For capturing digits for the *id*, matching the comma and capture word characters for the *name*:

```
(?<id>\d+),(?<name>\w+)
```

```js
const test = '00000001,name1,00000002,name2,00000003,name3,00000004,name4';
const result = Array.from(
  test.matchAll(/(?<id>\d+),(?<name>\w+)/g),
  m => m.groups
);
console.log(result);
```

If you want to capture all characters for the *id* and *name* except for a comma or whitespace char you can use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^,\s]+`

```
(?<id>[^,\s]+),(?<name>[^,\s]+)
```

```js
const test = '00000001,name1,00000002,name2,00000003,name3,00000004,name4';
const result = Array.from(
  test.matchAll(/(?<id>[^,\s]+),(?<name>[^,\s]+)/g),
  m => m.groups
);
console.log(result);
```